# I'm having problems understanding how this Java works with the arguments I'm feeding it

Tags: java, class, sum

The issue I'm having is understanding this code when running the command:
java Driver 1000000
its returning:
sum(1000000) = 1784293664

and no matter how long i try to look at it i cant understand why and how the code is doing this im just wondering if anyone can provide any help in understanding what this code actually does to the number?

```
class Sum
{
  private int sum;

  public int get() {
    return sum;
  }

  public void set(int sum) {
    this.sum = sum;
  }
}

class Summation implements Runnable
{
  private int upper;
  private Sum sumValue;

  public Summation(int upper, Sum sumValue) {
    this.upper = upper;
    this.sumValue = sumValue;
  }

  public void run() {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= upper; i++)
      sum += i;

    sumValue.set(sum);
  }
}

public class Driver
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length != 1) {
      System.err.println("Usage Driver <integer>");
      System.exit(0);
    }

    if (Integer.parseInt(args[0]) < 0) {
      System.err.println(args[0] + " must be >= 0");
      System.exit(0);
    }

    // Create the shared object
    Sum sumObject = new Sum();
    int upper = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    Thread worker = new Thread(new Summation(upper, sumObject));
    worker.start();

    try {
      worker.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) { }
    System.out.println("sum(" + upper + ") = " + sumObject.get());
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Andrew

Comment: Integer Overflow, is the most obvious answer. Try using `long` instead.

Comment: The correct sum is 500000500000 - obviously a long is required

Comment: @NRitH how did you arrive at that conclusion?

Comment: As a side note, i suppose you should make Sum#get and Sum#set synchronized. The example will perhaps work, but the lack of proper synchronization will bite you once you have multiple threads accessing an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Summing the numbers 1 through 1 million:

```
(1 + 1000000) * 1000000 / 2 = 500000500000
```

This causes overflow in the `int` you're using to hold the sum.  The result is:

```
500000500000 (mod 2^32) = 1784293664
```

Use a `long` to store the sum; it has a [maximum value of `9223372036854775807`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Long.MAX_VALUE) and can hold the sum.

Comment: This is one of my plights with java really. Why would you not make integer overflow throw a runtime error(that can be caught of course)? This isn't C for heaven's sake.

Comment: @Cruncher - Why would you add the (potentially significant, relatively) overhead of detecting an overflow at runtime to every instance when it won't even be posssible in probably 99.9% of instances?

Comment: @rgettman can i just ask how you got that math from the code i cant figure out how the sum is made with the code?

Comment: @James Because this isn't C.

Comment: @user2812073 http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/57919.html guass figured out how to do this a long time ago

Comment: @Cruncher Just because it's not C doesn't mean that performance isn't a legitimate goal in the language design.  Java gets a bad enough rep for performance already - you're effectively asking to halve the performance of math across the language, to help prevent people from shooting themselves in the foot in a case that doesn't apply the vast majority of the time.  It's simply a bad tradeoff.